# changing value of the form inside .module

Tags: hooks, theming, emails

I have a field in my newsletter, where user can enter his custom css.
That css is being applied for emails that are sent as newsletters.
Since I kinda want to create a default template, I'd rather import that CSS to my custom `.module`.
This is how form currently looks like (form that calls CSS):

```
$form['simplenews_template']['simplenews_template_style']["simplenews_template_css_$tid"] = array(
    '#type' => 'textarea',
    '#title' => t('CSS'),
    '#description' => t('Enter the CSS rules of the body.'),
    '#default_value' => _simplenews_template_get_css($tid),
  );
```

Is it possible that instead of `_simplenews_template_get_css($tid)` I put CSS code like `body {background:red};` or at least call a `file.css` that will contain same css code inside and make all email outputs default and how would code look like ?

Thanks,
Michael

Comment: and the question is?

Comment: @AdrianCidAlmaguer if it's possible, how would css i provided as example look like ?

Comment: What does this _simplenews_template_get_css function return?

Comment: @Shabir `function _simplenews_template_get_css($tid) {
  return variable_get("simplenews_template_css_$tid", '');
}`